# Integral closure

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, notation, algebraic-number-theory

Let $A\subset B$ be commutative rings with unit. Is there any standard notation for the integral closure of $B$ over $A$? I can't find any, not on the internet, nor on any algebraic number theory books I know. I find it to be absolutely horrible to write "and $A'$ be the integral closure of $B$ over $A$" every time I need it. Therefore, a notation would be convenient.

If there are none, what do you think of this one?
$$\mathfrak{C}(B/A)$$ 
it is elegant, the $\mathfrak{C}$ stands for $closure$, which is the right word in both English and French, and I didn't find this notation anywhere else. Also, we can recycle it in $$\mathfrak{C}(A)$$ to denote the integral closure of $\mathrm{Frac}(A)$ over $A$.

However, it is very different to the notation $$\mathcal{O}_K,$$ where $K$ is a number field, and we can clearly not use the notation $\mathcal{C}(A/B)$ for our purposes.

I would love to hear your suggestions, remarks, and anything you would have to say. Thanks.

EDIT #1: Maybe $$\mathfrak{C}_1(B/A)$$ would be nice, it is quite visual and the $1$ reminds us that we are interested in unitary polynomials.

Comment: The notation for the topological closure is also used: $\overline{\!A}$

Comment: In field theory, it is mainly used to denote the algebraic closure of a field. It is therefore a terrible idea to use this notation.

Comment: You should always explain your notations beforehand anyway, and your objections depend on the context.

Comment: Absolutely! But that doesn't exclude the usefulness of a "standard" notation.

Comment: The most commonly used is $A'$.

Comment: If you want to have a notation for yourself, do whatever you want. If you want to introduce a notation here that is going to spread around the world and be used by everybody, you're not being realistic.

Comment: That's not my goal at all. I just think this is a great place to gather constructive criticism and idea from people working in many different areas. And even if I am the only one to use this notation, it remains a good idea to have other people's opinion!